# Format a partition with ubuntu on it

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I would like to format my partitions with Ubuntu on them. How can I find them in Gparted ?

[image: gparted screenshot]

Comment: Do you want to delete all the partitions and use ubuntu then?

Comment: Or he wants to delete Ubuntu.

Comment: If you want to delete  ubuntu partition, then its `/dev/sda7` and `/dev/sda8` for linux swap.

Comment: @kashish: I believe your comment holds the answer. Would you mind converting it to one? :-)

Comment: @DavidFoerster Ok, I did it ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete Ubuntu, Then you will have to delete `/dev/sda7` and `/dev/sda8`.

You can delete these two partitions by logging into windows and deleting the above two partitions. A good tutorial to delete a partition in windows is [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/delete-a-hard-disk-partition#1TC=windows-7).

If you want to delete the partition using ubuntu, you will have to boot into live cd, click *Try ubuntu* and use software called `gnome-disks` to delete a partition.

Comment: @DavidFoerster done.

Comment: @kashish : How does this remove the GRUB boot loader, when /dev/sda1 is not even touched ? When you want to purge GRUB, you will have to mount the EFI partition and then remove the ubuntu folder and its content. :)

Comment: @cl-netbox Thank you for your comment. I edited my answer to remove wrong info.

Comment: @kashish: Have my up-vote.